# Coinmarketcap API Call with PHP

Tags: php, json, api, coinmarketcap

I tried my first API call but something is still wrong. I added my API-Key, choose the symbol and tried to echo the price. But it is still not valid. But my echo is still 0. Maybe someone show me what i did wrong. Thank you!

```
    <?php

$coinfeed_coingecko_json = file_get_contents('https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?symbol=ETH');
$parameters = [
  'start' => '1',
  'limit' => '2000',
  'convert' => 'USD'
];

$headers = [
  'Accepts: application/json',
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: XXX'
];

$qs = http_build_query($parameters); // query string encode the parameters
$request = "{$url}?{$qs}"; // create the request URL

$curl = curl_init(); // Get cURL resource
// Set cURL options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $request,            // set the request URL
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,     // set the headers 
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1         // ask for raw response instead of bool
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); // Send the request, save the response
print_r(json_decode($response)); // print json decoded response
curl_close($curl); // Close request

$coinfeed_json = json_decode($coinfeed_coingecko_json, false);

$coinfeedprice_current_price = $coinfeed_json->data->{'1'}->quote->USD->price;


?>
 <?php  echo $coinfeedde = number_format($coinfeedprice_current_price, 2, '.', '');  ?>
```

API Doc: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest

Comment: The params you have are for a differnent end point FYI. ListingsLatest supports those params but your url is calling QuotesLatest. Your issue though is you're not selecting the correct part of the JSON response. Just a guess but `$coinfeed_json->data->{'1'}->quote->USD->price` might be close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I added to my question but it is still 0. Maybe someone else now whats wrong. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot going on in your code.

- First of all $url was not defined
- Second of all you made two requests, one of which I have removed
- Third; you can access the json object by `$json->data[0]->quote->USD->price`
- Fourth; I removed the invalid request params

I have changed a few things to make it work:

```php
$url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest";

$headers = [
  'Accepts: application/json',
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: ___YOUR_API_KEY_HERE___'
];

$request = "{$url}"; // create the request URL

$curl = curl_init(); // Get cURL resource
// Set cURL options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $request,            // set the request URL
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,     // set the headers 
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1         // ask for raw response instead of bool
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); // Send the request, save the response
$json = json_decode($response);
curl_close($curl); // Close request

var_dump($json->data[0]->quote->USD->price);
var_dump($json->data[1]->quote->USD->price);
```

Comment: It is working now! Thank you very much. What i have to do with this "float" if i only what to show prices and numbers like supply. And i need to choose data or currency with a slug. How can i do this?

Comment: ok great.. could you accept this answer? If you have any other questions, maybe you can consider creating a new question for it.

Comment: Sure. But how can we remove this float? I can't use it with this.

Comment: float is the type of the variable, it is outputted by var_dump. So just assign the price to a variable and print the variable: ```$price = $json->data[1]->quote->USD->price; echo $price;```

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Now i only need this slug option. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I added a second question. Maybe we can find an answers for the last question i have in this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Do i have to change the URL and let data at 0?